# PayPal: Configure your firewall settings before October 2017

Tags: magento-1.9, paypal, payment-gateway, paypal-pro

I received this email from PayPal:
*As part of our on-going commitment to provide a more robust service, Payflow will be introducing additional IP addresses to both the production and pilot environments. To minimize potential impact, we recommend that you use Domain Name Service (DNS) host names instead of hard-coding Payflow IP addresses.
However, if you must allow particular IP addresses through your firewall or proxy servers, please review our list of Payflow IP addresses to ensure that the appropriate IPs are configured in your firewall/proxy settings before mid-October 2017.*
How to verify PayPal configuration in my magento 1.9?
Thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to contact your hosting provider. You can't change firewall settings unless you have your own dedicated server.